# Trouble with objects and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have problems taking individual data from an array. Searched the internet for about 2 hours with no succes. Code as followed:

```
$id_name = $this->name->Text;
$finder = prdtblRecord::finder();
$result = $finder->findAllByname($id_name);
$row_cnt = count($result);

if($row_cnt == 0)
{
    $this->failed_id($param);
}

if($row_cnt == 1)
{
    $this->id->Text = $result->id;
    $this->name->Text = $result->name;
    $this->adresse->Text = $result->adresse;
    $this->plz->Text = $result->plz;
    $this->ort->Text = $result->ort;
    $this->firma->Text = $result->firma;
}
```

The problem refers to the `$result->id`.
Error  is `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Thanks for reply and best regards.

Comment: can you print $result

Comment: $result is not an object. var_dump() it and see what it is.

Comment: It is an array found that out via var_dump().

Comment: what was the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you have array of object try to add `[0]`

```
$this->id->Text = $result[0]->id;
```

Comment: Hell yeah! Works now, searched for that bug for 2 hours.

Comment: Can you may explain what the "[0]" changes?

Comment: You have `array of single object` like `[{name:'Myname'}]` and was trying to assume only object like `{name:'Myname'}`